# Disjoint Union of Dyadic Cubes in Calderon-Zygmund Decomposition

Tags: real-analysis, harmonic-analysis

In proving the existence of a countable collection of disjoint dyadic cubes which we denote $B_{j}$ with $f \geq 0, f \in L^{1}(\mathbb{R}^{n}), \lambda > 0$ and we define $E_{t}f:= \sum_{B \in \{\text{dyadic cubes}\}}(\frac{1}{\mu(B)}\int_{B}f)\chi_{B}$ where $\chi$ denotes the indicator function. satisfying:

1. $ f \leq \lambda a.e.$ on $(\cup B_{j})^{c}$
2. $\mu(\cup B_{j}) \leq \frac{1}{\lambda}||f||_{L^{1}}$
   3.$\lambda < \frac{1}{\mu(B_{j}} \int_{b_{j}}f \leq 2^{n} \lambda. \forall j$

One defines the set $\Omega_{t}:= \{x \in \mathbb{R}^{n}: E_{t}f(x) > \lambda, E_{j}f(x) \leq \lambda, \forall j < t\}$ i.e. the larget dyadic cube whose average is geater than $ \lambda$.

**Question:** The $\Omega_{t}$ is a disjoint union of elements of $\{\text{dyadic cubes}\}$. What does this mean? I'm only familiar with disjoint union in the sense given in the following link: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint_union

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is something wrong in your definition of $E_t f$. It does not depend on $t$... I am copying below a proof of Calderon-Zygmund theorem.

**Theorem Calderon-Zygmund**
Let $f\in L^{1}\left(\mathbb{R}^{N}\right)  $ be a nonnegative function, and let $\lambda>0$. Then there
exists a countable family $\left\{  Q_{n}\right\}  $ of open mutually
disjoint cubes such that
\begin{equation}
f\left(  x\right)  \leq \lambda \quad \text{ for }\mathcal{L}^{N}\text{ a.e. }%
x\in\mathbb{R}^{N}\setminus\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}\overline{Q_{n}},
\end{equation}
and for every $n\in\mathbb{N}$,
\begin{equation}
\lambda<\frac{1}{\left\vert Q_{n}\right\vert }\int_{Q_{n}}f\left(  x\right)
\,dx\leq2^{N}\lambda\text{.} 
\end{equation} 
**Proof:** Choose $L>0$ so large enough
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}^{N}}f\left(  x\right)  \,dx\leq \lambda L^{N}\text{.}%
$$
Decompose $\mathbb{R}^{N}$ into a rectangular grid such that each cube $Q$ of
the partition has side length $L$. Since $f\ge 0$ we have
\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{\left|  Q\right|  }\int_{Q}f\left(  x\right)  \,dx=\frac{1}{L^N  }\int_{Q}f\left(  x\right)  \,dx\le \frac{1}{L^N  } \int_{\mathbb{R}^{N}}f\left(  x\right)  \,dx
\leq \lambda .
\end{equation}
Fix one such cube $Q$ and subdivide it into $2^{N}$ congruent subcubes. Let
$Q^{\prime}$ be one of these subcubes. If
$$
\frac{1}{\left|  Q^{\prime}\right|  }\int_{Q^{\prime}}f\left(  x\right)
\,dx>\lambda,
$$
and in view of the fact that
$$
\frac{1}{\left|  Q^{\prime}\right|  }\int_{Q^{\prime}}f\left(  x\right)
\,dx\leq\frac{2^{N}}{\left|  Q\right|  }\int_{Q}f\left(  x\right)
\,dx\leq2^{N}\lambda,
$$
then $Q^{\prime}$ will be selected
as one of the good cubes $Q_{n}$. On the other hand, if
$$
\frac{1}{\left|  Q^{\prime}\right|  }\int_{Q^{\prime}}f\left(  x\right)
\,dx\leq \lambda
$$
(note that since $\int_{\mathbb{R}^{N}}f\left(  x\right)  \,dx\leq \lambda L^{N}$ there is at least one), then we subdivide
$Q^{\prime}$ into $2^{N}$ congruent subcubes and we repeat the process.

In this way we construct a family of cubes $\left\{  Q_{n}\right\}  $ for
which \begin{equation}
\lambda<\frac{1}{\left\vert Q_{n}\right\vert }\int_{Q_{n}}f\left(  x\right)
\,dx\leq2^{N}\lambda\text{.} 
\end{equation}  is satisfied, and it remains to prove $f\left(  x\right)  \leq \lambda$  for $\mathcal{L}^{N}$  a.e. $
x\in\mathbb{R}^{N}\setminus\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}\overline{Q_{n}}$. It
can be seen from the construction that the cubes that were not selected to
belong to the family $\left\{  Q_{n}\right\}  $ form a fine covering
$\mathcal{F}$ of $\mathbb{R}^{N}\setminus\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}\overline
{Q_{n}}$. Therefore if $x\in\mathbb{R}^{N}\setminus\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty
}\overline{Q_{n}}$ is a Lebesgue point for $f$, then by Lebesgue differentiation theorem we have
$$
f\left(  x\right)  =\limsup_{\operatorname*{diam}F\rightarrow0\text{,}%
\,F\in\mathcal{F}\text{, }x\in F}\frac{1}{\left|  F\right|  }\int_{F}f\left(
y\right)  \,dy\leq \lambda
$$
and the proof is completed.